# Regex for numbers with & without comma

Tags: excel, regex

it might be an easy solution but I am trying few hours to pull some numbers from outlook to excel via macro. Email has line with "Attendance" and i need the figure afterwards. Figure could be from 1 to 10,000.

```
((Attendance\w*)\s*(\w*)\s*(\w*)\s*(\w*)\s*([\d-\.]*))
```

it works for the numbers without comma but shows only the first number before comma for the numbers with comma.

Has anyone got solution for that pleas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(Attendance.*?)([0-9,]{1,6})
```

**Edit:** Added parenthesis as it seems to be needed in an Excel macro working across columns.

Comment: I tried but no luck.. Just one more thing...Attendance figure is coming from the table in email. Attendance and its figure are two adjacent cells. I tried your code with \s* but did not work..

Comment: Just add parenthesis and magically it worked. Thanks @zb226. Much Appreciated...

Comment: What about `"Attendance,"`?

Comment: @Raif Glad to have helped :) Do you mean parenthesis as in `(Attendance.*?)([0-9,]{1,6})`?

Comment: @zb226 yep, exactly. :)

Comment: @Raif: Ah OK, so this seems to be related to the excel-setup, I'm adding it to the answer...